# Replace Space with New Line in Python

Tags: python, replace

I'm trying to replace '\s' with '\n', but when I print `line2`, it doesn't print a line with the spaces replaced with new lines. Could anybody indicate what's wrong with my syntax?

```
for line in fi:
    if searchString in line:
        line2 = line.replace('\s' , '\n') 
        print line2
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\s` is a Regex token, won't be understood by `str.replace`.

Do:

```
line.replace(' ', '\n')
```

Answer (score 5):

`.replace()` replaces strings, you want `re.sub(..)`, e.g.:

```
for line in fi:
    if searchString in line:
        line2 = re.sub(r'\s' , '\n', line) 
        print line2
```

The documentation has more details: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub